# How do I delete/break a symbolic link in Lion?

Tags: macos, ssd, symlink

I've made a symbolic link from my SSD to my HDD incorrectly and want to keep the folder on my SSD. How can I delete or break the symlink? Is there a Terminal command that will delete every symbolic link on my Mac?

Answer (score 8):

You can delete the symlink the same way as any other file. It will not follow the link. You can do this in finder by moving the link to the trash, or from the command line using `rm path/to/symlink`.

Do not attempt to remove all symlinks on your computer. They are used by the system in some places, such as frameworks.

Comment: So just put the receiving folder into the trash and job done? Thandks

Comment: What do you mean receiving? The link or the actual folder? Deleting the link itself will leave the folder alone, and deleting the folder will leave a link that points to a non-existing folder.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I get you now. Cheers